# Generate in TypeScript with color, with and height a base64 string

Tags: typescript, base64

I am trying to find out if I can generate a base64 code with the following 3 values: `color`,`width`, `height`. (Without external giants npm lib) I've only encountered a lib called base64-js. however, i do not need most functionalities.

Edit: Thanks to Victor. i edit his code a bit and the result is:

```
convertToDataURLViaCanvas(outputFormat, width, height, color) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.createElement('CANVAS');
        canvas.height = height;
        canvas.width = width;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // fill the entire canvas with color
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        // callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null;
        resolve(dataURL);
    });
}
```

Works like a charm. Thanks for this!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do (the question is too vague in details), but maybe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) is what you need

Comment: I try to write a angular component for that i need a placeholder image for skeleton loading. because for special reasons i want that the container size comes from the image size. so i need to define a placeholder image before the real image is loadet. i have 3 values. `color`, `width` & `heigh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said @HB, a `div` should be enough for such a placeholder. However, if you need a Base64 encoded image you can obtain it using `canvas.toDataURL()`:

```
function insertPlaceholder(color, width, height) {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        img = new Image();

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    img.src = canvas.toDataURL(); //-> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
insertPlaceholder('red', 250, 250);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly that what i was looking for! i change some small things. i edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is just an encoding which does not necessarily have anything to do with images. If you just need a placeholder i would recommend not adding the image until it is loaded and display a sized `div` instead.

If you really need to have an image there you can just make the source an SVG, which you do not even need to encode to Base64, because its data is already text. So it looks something like this:

```
data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ... >
```

Then you just need to set the relevant properties to size it and add the color.

```js
const addImage = (width, height, color) =>
{
  const image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="${width}px" height="${height}px">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="${color}"/>
  </svg>`;
  document.body.appendChild(image);
}

addImage(200, 100, 'red');
```